# Upgrading Laravel Spark to v5.0 from v4.0

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-spark

I upgraded my application from Laravel v5.4 to v5.5. I need to upgrade Laravel Spark from v4.0 to v5.0 as Spark 5.0 is a free upgrade for Spark applications and provides compatibility with Laravel 5.5.

The best and easiest way to upgrade Spark is via Spark CLI

`php artisan spark:update --major`

But as Spark v6.0 is available which is not a free upgrade from Spark v5.0 or lower, I get the following error:

```
In RequestException.php line 113:

  Client error: `GET https://spark.laravel.com/api/releases/6.0.10/download?api_token=<redacted>` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:
  {
      "message": ""
  }
```

When I try to upgrade using composer by upgrading the dependency in my `composer.json` file and run the `composer update` command:

`"laravel/spark": "~5.0"`

I get the following error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package laravel/spark ~5.0 exists as laravel/spark[4.0.x-dev, dev-master] but these are rejected by your constraint.
```

In the Spark [doc](https://spark.laravel.com/docs/5.0/upgrade), it says "If you installed Spark via the spark CLI tool, you may run the spark:update Artisan command" and "If you installed Spark via Composer, you may simply upgrade your dependency in your composer.json file and run the composer update command:". I don't remember whether I had installed Spark via the spark CLI tool or Composer, but it looks like I had used the spark CLI tool. The second error could be because I had used the spark CLI tool while installing Spark as the installing or updating using composer needed few more code to be added to `composer.json` file. So, I replaced the following

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "./spark"
    }
]
```

with

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://spark-satis.laravel.com"
    }
]
```

After this modification, when I try to run `composer update`, I get the following error:

```
  - Removing laravel/spark (dev-master)
  - Installing laravel/spark (v5.0.3): Downloading (failed)    Failed to download laravel/spark from dist: The "https://api.github.com/repos/laravel/spark/zipball/cb75558d1243be5e08f4932d01383ef123d1fb05" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)
    Now trying to download from source
```

How can I upgrade Spark from v4.0 to v5.0?

Comment: Since Spark is closed source I'd ask maintainers for assisting in a first place. Did you attempt to do that?

Comment: @Kyslik Yes, I did. But I have not got any response yet.

Comment: @Debiprasad Hi, did you resolve it? Currently in the same situation but with different version v3 to v4.

Comment: @JimM No, I did not get any help or response.